# How to specify xy position where pixmap will be drawn?

Tags: c++, qt

How to specify the 'xy' position where the `pixmap` will be drawn inside of the `QLabel`?

```
QLabel* label = new QLabel("test", ui.pushButton);
label->setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200);
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.load("...");
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(w, h, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
label->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

I know that is possible to **move** the label, but i would like to understand how to specify the position instead of moving it.

Comment: You need to be more clear, like saying 'position of the pixmap within a label', or just using the term 'padding'.

Answer (score 0):

Set the alignment first and then use the `setContentsMargins()` method or the `padding` style sheet property, like the following.

```
// Firstly
label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
// Secondly do this
label->setContentsMargins(100, 50, 0, 0);
// or this
label->setStyleSheet("padding: 50 0 0 100");
```